# Disk structuring element in opencv

Tags: opencv

I know a disk structuring element can be created in MATLAB as following:

```
se=strel('disk',4); 

 0     0     1     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     1     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     1     0     0
```

Is there any function or method or any other way of creating the structuring element same as above in opencv. I know we can manually create it using loops but I just want to know if some function exist for that.

Answer (score 5):

The closest one (not the exact same) you can get in OpenCV is by calling [**`getStructuringElement()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphologyex#getstructuringelement):

```
int sz = 4;
cv::Mat se = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(2*sz-1, 2*sz-1));
```

, which gives the matrix with values

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks but what how large will the effect be on morphological operations using this structuring element rather than the structuring element created in MATLAB. Also what if we want to create a ball shaped structuring element? Thanks

Comment: @Navdeep I am not sure how large this will cause side effects. For custom shaped structuring element, in OpenCV, you can look into the `CV_SHAPE_CUSTOM` shape parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
def estructurant(radius):
    kernel = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1) ,np.uint8)
    y,x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
    mask = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
    kernel[mask] = 1
    kernel[0,radius-1:kernel.shape[1]-radius+1] = 1
    kernel[kernel.shape[0]-1,radius-1:kernel.shape[1]-radius+1]= 1
    kernel[radius-1:kernel.shape[0]-radius+1,0] = 1
    kernel[radius-1:kernel.shape[0]-radius+1,kernel.shape[1]-1] = 1
    return kernel
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`skimage.morphology.disk`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.disk), which produces a symmetric result (unlike `cv2.getStructuringElement`):

```
>>> disk(4)

array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```